# Auto Start C++ on qemu using Yocto

Tags: linux, qemu, autostart, recipe, yocto-recipe

i have this problem that i have created a QT console program C++  and moved that project to my meta-layer and created a .bb file for it and i wanted this program to auto start when i run qemu but for some reason it doesn't
Here is my recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple hello world application"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COREBASE}/meta/files/common-licenses/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

DEPENDS += " qtbase"
FILES_${PN} += " ${bindir}/QTServer "

inherit qmake5


SRC_URI = "file://main.cpp \
       file://myserver.cpp \
       file://myserver.h \
       file://QTServer.pro \
       "

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install(){

    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0775 QTServer ${D}${bindir}
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
    install -m 0775 QTServer ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/QTServer
}

INITSCRIPT_NAME = "QTServer"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "start 05 5 2 3 . stop 22 0 1 6 ."
```

just  added in my do_install

```
        install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d
    install -m 0775 QTServer ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/QTServer
```

and set the program to run at specific initrun levels

```
INITSCRIPT_NAME = "QTServer"
INITSCRIPT_PARAMS = "start 05 5 2 3 . stop 22 0 1 6 ."
```

nothing literally happen even tho i found the file installed it the etc/init.d

Answer (score 0):

I just found it was missing  `inherit update-rc.d`